# AppleScript as .app does not take arguments from command line

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line-arguments

I try to process command line arguments in a AppleScript. The script works if I run it using `osascript TestArgs.scpt a.txt b.txt`. But if I save the script as an .app and run it from the command line, it does not show any arguments: `open -a TestArgs --args a.txt b.txt` does not work. I also tried several variations of the script with no success.

```
on run argv
    set argc to 0
    try
        set argc to (count of argv)
    end try
    tell application "Finder" to display dialog ("Argument Count: " & argc as string)
end run
```

It seems the problem is realted to OSX 10.8, as the same script works as expected on 10.7

Where is my mistake?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been long searching for a solution myself too. Since there is not an approved solution yet, I would like to point out to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57700497/4216175) posted by [red_menace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10853463/red-menace). There you find an AppleScript code which exactly answers the original posted question, how to run an Applescript applications with command line arguments.

To give credits, the AppleScript code there is reminiscent of the [JavaScript application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44313903/4216175) posted by [user137369](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1661012/user137369).

Answer (score 2):

There’s a way to do it with JXA (JavaScript for Automation), which may be an acceptable solution. It uses the Objective-C bridge, so it may be possible with AppleScript as well. This was mostly [taken from the JXA Cookbook](https://github.com/dtinth/JXA-Cookbook/wiki/Shell-and-CLI-Interactions#arguments).

The equivalent JXA to the AppleScript in this question would use:

```
function run(argv) {
  …
}
```

But it suffers from the same issue of not working when compiled to an app. You can get around that by starting your code with

```
ObjC.import('Foundation')
const args = $.NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments
const argv = []
const argc = args.count
for (let i = 0; i < argc; i++) { argv.push(ObjC.unwrap(args.objectAtIndex(i))) }
delete args
```

User-given arguments will then start at `argv[1]`, as `argv[0]` will be the applet itself.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using the osascript with the app? That works. You basically have 2 ways to pass args. These work for a scpt or app...

1) from command line: osascript /path/to/script arg1 arg2

2) from another script: run script file path:to:script with parameters {arg1, agr2}.

Comment: Well, as it is stated in the first line of my question -- this is my solution for the moment. But it wold be great to identify the issue. So I know if it is my mistake or a bug/feature of AppleScript. I'ts not a solution if you'd like to hand the script to an less experienced user.

Comment: I can't answer why "open" doesn't work. However I don't see how an inexperienced user would have more of a problem issuing "osascript" versus "open". They seem to be the same in their complexity. The 2nd suggestion I gave you would probably be the easiest for a user. You could setup the applescript and the user would only have to enter parameters and press the run button. Did you try that?

Comment: Ok, so may be you are right on that point. In case of passing cmd line arguments the user always needs to use a terminal and thus the needed level is the same. Thus your approach using a dialog is very user friendly. Thank you for that. But for me the question remains: Why does it work in OSX 10.7 but not in 10.8?

Comment: There’s a valid reason to want it to run from a .app. When [showing a notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627018/change-the-icon-of-an-applescript-called-notification/), the icon only shows if it’s a .app, not when it’s a .scptd.

Comment: Another reason to want to run it as an app is you can code sign the app and grant the signed app accessibility access.  Without that access, lots of Applescript commands like "check theCheckbox" will no longer work in 10.9 and later.  As far as I've been able to find, there is no way to grant access to osascript in 10.9 and later, and no way to pass command line args to a signed applescript app. This knowledge brought to you by: Hours of Frustration.