# Change the icon of an applescript-called notification

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mavericks

With OSX Mavericks we now can make [notifications with applescript](http://www.macosautomation.com/mavericks/notifications/index.html) pretty easily. However, there doesn’t seem to be a way to change the icon that appears to a custom one. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display notification` will take application icon. You can set icon in bunlde content of applescript application.

```
set fileName to choose file "Select a Folder"
display notification "Parag Bafna" subtitle "Its working" & fileName
```

[image]

```
display notification    text    required
with title  text    optional
subtitle    text    optional
sound name  text    optional
```

Comment: "display notification' does not seem to take an icon. Even the documentation for display notification that you provided does not show any indication of icon inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You change the icon by simply changing the icon of the script/app itself. Copy a picture you want as icon (⌘ + C), Right click your saved app/script file, "get info", click the upper left file icon, Paste (⌘ + V). If you save as a script bundle, you can also swap the icns file inside the bundle to your own (inside the Resources folder).